# Errors when running $reindex on HAPI FHIR server

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I've added a couple of custom search parameters to a HAPI Fhir server (SMILES CDR 2021.02.R05) which doesn't have the automatic indexing turned on. According to the docs:

> To reindex all resources, simply call the $reindex operation with no parameters.

However, when I POST "{FHIR_URL}/$reindex" I get the following error:

> 'Invalid request: The FHIR endpoint on this server does not know how to handle POST operation[$reindex] with parameters [[]]'

Oddly, even if I provide a body with a Parameters resource such as below, I get the same error about empty parameters...which makes me think I'm just doing something stupid.

```
{
    "resourceType": "Parameters", 
    "parameter": [
        {
        "name": "url",
        "valueString": "ObservationDefinition?"
        },
        {
        "name": "url",
        "valueString": "ActivityDefinition?"
        }]
}
```

The headers include the necessary basic auth (for the dev server) and content-type set to 'application/fhir+json'